# How do I display the correct LocationProvinceCode either US or Canadian?

Tags: xml, xslt

I would like to display the correct `<nc:LocationCanadianProvinceCode>` or `<nc-3.0.1:LocationStateUSPostalServiceCode>` based on the

`/Integration/Party/Address/State` found in the xml document and by checking if that state code exist in the referring xml document.

My xsl is working but it is displaying both US and Canadian State codes. I just want to display one State code for each address.

**Desired output**

```
        <nc:Address>
        <nc:LocationStreet>
            <nc:StreetFullText>200 Burrard Street</nc:StreetFullText>
            <nc:StreetFullText/>
            <nc:StreetFullText/>
        </nc:LocationStreet>
        <nc:LocationCityName>Vancouver</nc:LocationCityName>
        <nc:LocationCanadianProvinceCode>BC</nc:LocationCanadianProvinceCode>
        <nc:LocationPostalCode>65465</nc:LocationPostalCode>
    </nc:Address>
```

**My current wrong output**

```
<nc:Address>
    <nc:LocationStreet>
    <nc:StreetFullText>200 Burrard Street</nc:StreetFullText>
    <nc:StreetFullText/>
    <nc:StreetFullText/>            
        </nc:LocationStreet>
    <nc:LocationCityName>Vancouver</nc:LocationCityName>
    <nc:LocationCanadianProvinceCode>BC</nc:LocationCanadianProvinceCode>
    <nc-3.0.1:LocationStateUSPostalServiceCode>BC</nc-3.0.1:LocationStateUSPostalServiceCode>
    <nc:LocationPostalCode>65465</nc:LocationPostalCode>
</nc:Address>
```

**My sample xml document code**

```
<Integration xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" xmlns:tsg="http://tsgweb.com" xmlns:IXML="http://tsgweb.com" xmlns:CMCodeQueryHelper="urn:CMCodeQueryHelper" PackageID="DL Notice to DVS" MessageID="67093862" xmlns="">
    <Party ID="16769698" InternalPartyID="1614672736">
            <Address PartyCorrespondence="true" PartyCurrent="true" ID="17874134" Type="Non Standard">
            <AddressLine1>200 Burrard Street</AddressLine1>
            <AddressLine4>Vancouver, BC, 65465</AddressLine4>
            <City>Vancouver</City>
            <State>BC</State>
            <Zip>65465</Zip>
            <Foreign>false</Foreign>
        </Address>
    </Party>
</Integration>
```

**My xsl code - template for Subject where the Address Template is called**

```
<!--Template for ext Subject-->
<xsl:template name="Subject">
    <ext:Subject>
        <xsl:for-each select="/Integration/Case/CaseParty[Connection/@Word='DFD']/Address |     /Integration[not(Case/CaseParty[Connection/@Word='DFD']/Address)]/Party[@InternalPartyID=current()/@InternalPartyID]/Address[@PartyCurrent='true']">
            <xsl:call-template name="Address"/>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </ext:Subject>
</xsl:template>
```

**My xsl code - Template for address**

```
<!--Template Address-->
    <xsl:template name="Address">
        <xsl:variable name="vUsState" select="document(concat($gEnvPath,'\Schemas\NiemExchanges\DvsDriverLicenseNotification\niem\codes\usps_states\3.0\1\usps_states.xsd'))/xs:schema/xs:simpleType/xs:restriction/xs:enumeration[@value=current()/State]/@value"/>
        <xsl:variable name="vCanadianState" select="document(concat($gEnvPath,'\Schemas\NiemExchanges\DvsDriverLicenseNotification\niem\codes\canada_post\3.0\post-canada.xsd'))/xs:schema/xs:simpleType/xs:restriction/xs:enumeration[@value=current()/State]/@value"/>
        <nc:Address>
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="Block and ($vUsState or $vCanadianState)">
<!--Standard-->
                    <nc:LocationStreet>
                        <nc:StreetNumberText>
                            <xsl:value-of select="Block"/>
                        </nc:StreetNumberText>
                        <nc:StreetPredirectionalText>
                            <xsl:value-of select="PreDir"/>
                        </nc:StreetPredirectionalText>
                        <nc:StreetName>
                            <xsl:value-of select="Street"/>
                        </nc:StreetName>
                        <nc:StreetCategoryText>
                            <xsl:value-of select="AddrSfxKy"/>
                        </nc:StreetCategoryText>
                        <nc:StreetPostdirectionalText>
                            <xsl:value-of select="PostDir"/>
                        </nc:StreetPostdirectionalText>
                        <nc:StreetExtensionText>
                            <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(concat(UnitKy, ' ' , UnitNum))"/>
                        </nc:StreetExtensionText>
                    </nc:LocationStreet>
                    <nc:LocationCityName>
                        <xsl:value-of select="City"/>
                    </nc:LocationCityName>
                    <!--New Canadian Province-->
                    <nc:LocationCanadianProvinceCode>
                        <xsl:value-of select="State"/>
                    </nc:LocationCanadianProvinceCode>
                    <nc-3.0.1:LocationStateUSPostalServiceCode>
                        <xsl:value-of select="State"/>
                    </nc-3.0.1:LocationStateUSPostalServiceCode>
                    <nc:LocationPostalCode>
                        <xsl:value-of select="Zip"/>
                    </nc:LocationPostalCode>
                </xsl:when>
                <!--<xsl:when test="Foreign ='false'">-->
                <!--<xsl:when test="Foreign ='false' and ($vUsState or $vCanadianState)">-->
                <xsl:when test="Foreign ='false' and ($vUsState or $vCanadianState)">
<!--Non-Standard-->
                    <nc:LocationStreet>
                        <nc:StreetFullText>
                            <xsl:value-of select="AddressLine1"/>
                        </nc:StreetFullText>
                        <nc:StreetFullText>
                            <xsl:value-of select="AddressLine2"/>
                        </nc:StreetFullText>
                        <nc:StreetFullText>
                            <xsl:value-of select="AddressLine3"/>
                        </nc:StreetFullText>
                    </nc:LocationStreet>
                    <nc:LocationCityName>
                        <xsl:value-of select="City"/>
                    </nc:LocationCityName>
                    <!--New Canadian Province-->
                    <nc:LocationCanadianProvinceCode>
                        <xsl:value-of select="State"/>
                    </nc:LocationCanadianProvinceCode>
                    <nc-3.0.1:LocationStateUSPostalServiceCode>
                        <xsl:value-of select="State"/>
                    </nc-3.0.1:LocationStateUSPostalServiceCode>
                    <nc:LocationPostalCode>
                        <xsl:value-of select="Zip"/>
                    </nc:LocationPostalCode>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
<!--Foreign-->
                    <nc:AddressFullText>
                        <xsl:value-of select="concat(AddressLine1, '&#xa;')"/>
                        <xsl:value-of select="concat(AddressLine2, '&#xa;')"/>
                        <xsl:value-of select="concat(AddressLine3, '&#xa;')"/>
                        <xsl:value-of select="concat(AddressLine4, '&#xa;')"/>
                    </nc:AddressFullText>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </nc:Address>
    </xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your XML, the first `xsl:when` that will evaluate to true is this:

```
<xsl:when test="Foreign ='false' and ($vUsState or $vCanadianState)">
```

And within this you currently output both

```
<nc:LocationCanadianProvinceCode>
    <xsl:value-of select="State"/>
</nc:LocationCanadianProvinceCode>
<nc-3.0.1:LocationStateUSPostalServiceCode>
    <xsl:value-of select="State"/>
</nc-3.0.1:LocationStateUSPostalServiceCode>
```

What you probably need to do is use a nested `xsl:choose` here, to test `$vUsState` or `$vCanadianState` again

```
<xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="$vCanadianState">
        <nc:LocationCanadianProvinceCode>
            <xsl:value-of select="State"/>
        </nc:LocationCanadianProvinceCode>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
        <nc-3.0.1:LocationStateUSPostalServiceCode>
           <xsl:value-of select="State"/>
        </nc-3.0.1:LocationStateUSPostalServiceCode>
    </xsl:otherwise>
 </xsl:when>
```

You probably need to do something similar in the first `xsl:when` too.

Comment: Tim, as always, Thanks for your help